# error when trying to use pthread_create

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm trying to use `pthread_create` to create a thread that will run a function but I'm getting `incompatible type for argument 4 of pthread_create`.
I've seen some posts about this issue but none of the solutions that was offered there didn't solve it for me.

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
typedef struct {
    const char *filename;
    Queue *url_queue;
} FileReaderArguments;


void *file_reader(void *args) {
// function code..
}

void parallel_checker(const char *filename, int number_of_threads) {
        FileReaderArguments file_reader_arguments = {0};
        CollectorArguments collector_arguments = {0};
        pthread_t file_reader_thread, collector_thread;
        // PROBLEMATIC LINE
            pthread_create(file_reader_thread, NULL, &file_reader, file_reader_arguments);
        // END OF PROBLEMATIC LINE
        // more code..
}
```

Comment: The fourth argument needs to be a pointer - Yours isn't.

Comment: @tofro got it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The argument that is given to the your function is expected to be a pointer, because that is the only way to generalize types in C. When calling `pthread_create` you pass the *pointer* to the argument. See [this page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create), the compiler is expecting an argument of type `void *`—a pointer—while you are passing the whole structure variable.